# Est-ce qu'il y a une règle sur le nombre d'énumérations dans une phrase?

Tags: conjonctions, coordination, formulation, énumération

Prenons l'exemple suivant:

> Des gens sympathiques et courtois au cœur des succès et des échecs de
>   la journée.

Je sens que la construction avec deux énumérations (sympathiques/courtois et succès/échecs) est techniquement correcte mais qu'il s'agit d'une forme à éviter.

Existe-t-il une règle à ce sujet?

Comment: Parfois quand on accumule les énumérations, il arrive qu'on termine par un raton-laveur.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C'est une affaire de style, pas de grammaire, donc il n'y a pas de règle. Il faut juste faire attention s'il y a un risque d'ambiguïté, ce qui n'est pas le cas ici.

La succession d'énumérations tend à rendre la phrase lourde. Ce n'est en général pas considéré comme une qualité, mais des auteurs tout à fait reconnus usent (et diront certains abusent) de phrases très longues comportant beaucoup de subordonnées et d'énumération, ce qui est toutefois à réserver à quelqu'un qui a déjà fait ses preuves et qu'il vaut mieux éviter dans la vie courante, surtout dans un texte destiné à être compris plutôt qu'à être de la littérature. Il est difficile de juger avec seulement un fragment et non une phrase complète.

Comment: Un très joli exemple de phrase longue, s'approchant de la lourdeur stylistique qu'elle tend à décrire ! Si je pouvais je ferais +2 même :-) En matière de style, on cherchera en général à éviter les répétitions, notamment de conjonctions « et/et/et/et/… » et surtout on pensera à découper la phrase à l'aide d'un point ou d'une virgule pour laisser le lecteur reprendre son souffle.

Comment: @zmo Sans oublier l'usage du `;` Cf. le livre de Patrick Chamoiseau : "L'empreinte à Crusoé", un régal littéraire de phrases à périodes pour la sauvegarde de cette ponctuation oubliée